# Script to move a row between Google Sheets tabs once status changes, please

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet named Tracker, with two tabs, one named Workload and the other Archive. I'm trying to create a script that once the status in Column N (that has a dropdown menu) in tab Workload changes to either Complete or Cancelled, the full row moves from tab Workload to the bottom (first blank row) of tab Archive. However, I can't get the script to work. What am I doing wrong, please?

**Here is what I have:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheetName = "Tracker";
  var sourceTabName = "Workload";
  var destinationTabName = "Archive";
  var statusColumn = 14; // Column N

  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Check if the edited cell is in the correct sheet and column
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == sourceTabName && e.range.getColumn() == statusColumn) {
    var statusValue = e.value;

    // Check if the status is "Cancelled" or "Complete"
    if (statusValue == "Cancelled" || statusValue == "Complete") {
      // Move the entire row to the destination tab
      moveRowToDestination(sheet, e.range.getRow(), destinationTabName);
    }
  }
}

function moveRowToDestination(sheet, row, destinationTabName) {
  var data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var destinationTab = sheet.getSheetByName(destinationTabName);

  destinationTab.appendRow(data);
  sheet.deleteRow(row);
}
```

**And here is the message I'm getting:**

Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')
onEdit  @ Code.gs:7

Any help is very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: If you are trying to run the script from the script editor without supplying the event object.   The script is a handler function for and onEdit trigger which is only fired when someone edits a cell in a sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Workload" && e.range.columnStart == 14 && e.value ) {
    if (e.value == "Cancelled" || e.value == "Complete") {
      let dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Archive");
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
      sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper! Thank you for being so helpful! It's finally working now, but when the content moves to the Archive tab, I'm left with a blank row in the Workload tab. Do you know if there is something I can do so that the row will be deleted as well, please?
Thank you!!

Comment: oh I thought that moveTo would have deleted the line but I guess it just clears it.